# Error creating directory on linux server using PHP Code

Tags: php, linux

I have a group on linux named mygroup. and have a user named apache. apache is the member of mygroup.

i created a sample php file and uploaded on sever

```
    <?php

$structure = '/my_repo/hello';


if (!mkdir($structure, 0, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}

?>
```

myrepo dir is at root level and is group is mygroup and owner is root. permissions are 764.

when i accessed my file on http://mydomain.com/sample.php

it gives me the following error

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  dir(/my_repo/hello) 
[<a href='function.dir'>function.dir</a>]: failed to open dir: 
Permission denied in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/sample.php
```

Comment: seems like you don't have permissions to create directories in `/`. Does folder `/my_repo/` exists? Try to simply mkdir('/my_repo/'). What does it give?

Comment: Did you check your directory write permissions?

Comment: You get your answer with PHP warning. You dont have permissions to create a directory. In windows it's simple but in linux check your CHOWN of the script and directories etc.

Comment: /my_repo folder exists and its group is mygroup and owner is root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved. there was permission issue on server. the code was uploaded through a different user, that was not having permission to myrepo directory.